# SSRS is removing multiple lines in grouping

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Rtrim(ltrim(CUSTNAME)) as 'CUSTNAME',
ItemName,
ISNULL(NAME, LOGCREATEDBY) AS 'Modified By'
,b.ITEMID as 'Item Id'
,[PRICE_NEW] as 'New Price'
,[PRICE_OLD] as 'Old Price'
,[PRICEUNIT_NEW] as 'New Unit Price'
,[PRICEUNIT_OLD] as 'Old Unit Price'
,LOGCREATEDDATE as 'Created Date' 
,LOGCREATEDTIME
,(select Description from Dimensions where a.Dimension2_ = Dimensions.Num) as 'Division'
,(Select TOP 1 INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL From INVENTTRANS Where 

INVENTTRANS.ITEMID = B.ITEMID and InvoiceID like 'Inv%' order by INVENTTRANS.DATEFINANCIAL desc) As 'LastInvoice'
FROM PMF_INVENTTABLEMODULELOG AS b
    LEFT JOIN USERINFO ON ID = LOGCREATEDBY
    LEFT JOIN INVENTTABLE AS a on a.ITEMID in (b.itemId)
WHERE LOGCREATEDDATE between @beginCreatedDate and @endCreatedDate
and a.dimension2_ in (@dimension)
order by LOGCREATEDDATE,LOGCREATEDTIME  desc
```

What happens, in short, is it goes through a table and picks out an item number and lists each price change for that item.
the query, wen run, will return something like:

```
    CUSTNAME   |  Modified By  |  Item ID |  New Price |  Old Price
------------------------------------------------------------------
Performance        Joe             12345       21.50        21.49
Performance        Mary            12345       21.49        19.10
```

(This happens to be the return that is causing problem)

My report lists each line by division, Customer name and item Number. The problem is, when I have an Item ID group, it adds up the total (makes sense) So i get rid of the item number group, but now it will list only one item per customer!

it should show the two lines for Performance in the example, but instead, it lists neither. I would like it to show every single line for each customer. It must be the ITEM ID group, but I can't seem to get it right.

[image]

Comment: where is **(Details)** row in row groups?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting rid of the group, change it to show detail data.

Right click on the group select 'Group Properties' and select the Group On expression. Then click the delete button. It will then no longer sum as it is a detail group.

I would recommend that you then remove sum from the relevant expressions, to avoid confusion, as they will only be summing single values but will make it look otherwise.